# Paranoid: avoiding code duplication in/after loops

Tags: refactoring

I've got a bit strange question on code duplication. There are lots of loops like this:

```
    $prev_name = null;
    $clone = null;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      if($prev_name != $row['req']){    
        if($prev_name){
          while($clone <= $end){            
            echo '<td>-</td>';              
            $clone->step();
          }
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($prev_name = $row['req']) . '</td>';                                                                                                                                    
        $clone = clone $start;        
      }

      $rowdate = date_create($row['date']);
      while($clone < $rowdate){         
        echo '<td>-</td>';
        $clone->step();
      }

      echo '<td>' . $row[$field] . '</td>';
      $clone->step();
    }

    if($prev_name){
      while($clone <= $end){
        echo '<td>-</td>';
        $clone->step();
      }
      echo '</tr>';
    }
```

as you see if() after loop is the same as 2-nd if() in loop. is it possible to reduce this kind of duplication?

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a function.

```
 function writeSteps($prev_name,$clone,$end)
 {
    if($prev_name){
      while($clone <= $end){            
        echo '<td>-</td>';              
        $clone->step();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) is your friend.

Just put this code into a method and call it from both places.

```
if($prev_name){
  while($clone <= $end){            
    echo '<td>-</td>';              
    $clone->step();
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```